# In Perl, using File::Tail trying to grep pattern using regex, but $1 unintialised

Tags: regex, perl, tail

I am trying to continuously tail a growing file, and using regex to extract information whenever new lines are added to the file, but `$1` does not seem to like it.

Code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$| = 1;
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Tail;

my $file=File::Tail->new(
        name=>"sample.txt",
        maxinterval=>1,
        interval=>0.05);

while (defined(my $line=$file->read))
{
        chomp($line);
        print "$line\n";
        if ($line =~ m/ls/)
        {
                print $1;
                print "MATCH\n";
        }
}
```

Input to sample.txt, entered in bash shell

```
echo "test1" >> sample.txt
echo "test2" >> sample.txt
echo "test3" >> sample.txt
echo "testls4 >> sample.txt
```

Output

```
test1
test2
test3
testls4
Use of uninitialized value $1 in print at test.pl line 19.
MATCH
```

clearly, there is a match, since `MATCH` was displayed on the output, but why is `$1` still uninitialised? Strangely enough, outside of the `while` loop, I have no problems with `$1`

Comment: The regexp `/ls/` contains no capturing groups, so of course `$1`, `$2`, etc. are undefined after it succeeds. What did you expect to find in `$1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$1` and similar contain the strings captured by parentheses.  You need to surround your regex pattern with parentheses to have `$1` contain what you matched.

Comment: thanks! didn't know about backreferences, and adding parentheses worked `($line =~ m/(ls)/)`